# Getting select value to pass to POST

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm currently trying to find the best way to achieve this, i have an html form, with a  option, i need to get the value of the select via javascript, which i can do, then have it in a hidden input field to be sent in the POST.

**Partial HTML form:**

```
            <select onchange='getId(this.value)' name="article_domain" class="form-control" required="required">
                    <?php
                    $rows   = DB::getInstance()->select('SELECT * FROM `domains` ORDER BY `domain_date` DESC');
                    $secret = "";
                    $cost   = "";
                    ?>
                    <?php foreach ($rows as $row) { ?>
                        <?php $secret = $row['domain_id']; ?>
                        <?php $cost   = $row['domain_cost_pm']; ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['domain_id']) ?>">[DA<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['domain_da']) ?>][PA<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['domain_pa']) ?>][CF<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['domain_cf']) ?>][TF<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['domain_tf']) ?>][RD<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['domain_rd']) ?>][$<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['domain_cost_pm']) ?>][<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['domain_category']) ?>]</option>
                    <?php } ?>
            </select>
            </div>
        </div>              

         <div class="row form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-12 text-right">
                <input type="hidden" name="hiddenId" value="NEED_THE_ID_HERE" />
                <input type="hidden" name="hiddenCost" value="<?php echo $cost; ?>" />
                <button type="submit" name="submitAddArticle" class="btn btn-primary">Add Post</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getId(id) {
  theId = id;
}
</script>
```

I can alert the **theId** value fine which does contain the correct ID when the onChange is fired, i'm not sure the best way to pass it to here value="NEED_THE_ID_HERE" once it does go there i can then pass it to the POST once the form is submitted, any help would be appreciated, i'm not 100% sure with javascript at the moment i think i'm on the right track.

Comment: you mean something like `document.getElementsByName("hiddenId")[0].value = theId;`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add an `id` attribute on the hidden field :

```
<input type="hidden" name="hiddenId" id="hidden-id" value="" />
```

Then, in your JavaScript function, fill the input using [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getId(id) {
  document.querySelector("#hidden-id").value = id;
}
</script>
```

Or using [`getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getId(id) {
  document.getElementById("hidden-id").value = id;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, i just added an id tot eh input tag: <input type="hidden" name="hiddenId" id="hidden-id" value="" /> and tried both the options above, when i look in the source code the value="" /> stays blank, i will test again and post back.

Answer (score 1):

Can you give an id to your hidden input and then set the value with jQuery?

```
$("#yourHiddenInput").val(theId);
```